# Cannot access git actions with github cli with ssh, getting "git@github.com: Permission denied (public key)

Tags: windows, git, powershell, github, ssh

### The Problem

After setting everything up,  I am running the repo clone command to clone one of my repositories onto my local machine. However, I keep getting the same error message:

```
D:\0--Projekte ❯ gh repo clone wiktoriavh/ask-good-questions
Cloning into 'ask-good-questions'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Wiktoria/.ssh/id_ed25519':
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also get a similar error when trying to ssh into it:

```
~ ❯ ssh gh-cli
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Wiktoria\.ssh\id_ed25519':
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).                                                                19:16:01
~ ❯ ssh git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Wiktoria/.ssh/id_ed25519':
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am on Windows.

### What I tried

I have tried a few different things.

- `gh auth refresh` to refresh my authentication
- tried to use a new auth

  - created a new ssh key pair `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my@email.com"`
  - `gh auth logout` to logout of my gh cli
  - `gh auth login` and then I chose SSH, logged in through the browser and chose the new ssh key pair I created earlier. The public key is saved on github.
- I updated the `known_hosts` file with the following fingerprints: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints
- I updated the `~/.ssh/config` file to include github

```
Host gh-cli
        IdentityFile C:\Users\Wiktoria\.ssh\id_ed25519
        HostName github.com
        User git
        AddKeysToAgent yes
```

I am not sure what else I could try. I checked out help pages from GitHub and on StackOverflow.

### What I expect to happen

I expect to be able to do git actions with GitHub CLI through SSH.

---

### Some Updates

I have tried around, used `ssh-add` which seemed to help a littl, howerever I still am unable to clone. I can ssh into github, but not use the gh cli, or `git clone` for the matter.
The repository exists: https://github.com/wiktoriavh/ask-good-questions

[image]

I also checked if Port 22 is open, however, I did not change any OS host files.

[image]

Here is my host file. I tried uncomment the last two lines, but that didn't change anything.

[image]

This is the output when I do `ssh -vT git@github.com`:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\Wiktoria/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\Wiktoria/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Wiktoria\\.ssh\\id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Wiktoria\\.ssh\\id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-dd067d10
debug1: no match: babeld-dd067d10
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: C:\\Users\\Wiktoria/.ssh/known_hosts:3: parse error in hostkeys file
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug1: C:\\Users\\Wiktoria/.ssh/known_hosts:3: parse error in hostkeys file
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Wiktoria/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: w.dev+github@mailbox.org ED25519 SHA256:Z7r525AWfMxUAF8EFoZxznXQa/VU1jLba39P+XwiRIA agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Wiktoria\\.ssh\\id_ed25519  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: w.dev+github@mailbox.org ED25519 SHA256:Z7r525AWfMxUAF8EFoZxznXQa/VU1jLba39P+XwiRIA agent
debug1: Server accepts key: w.dev+github@mailbox.org ED25519 SHA256:Z7r525AWfMxUAF8EFoZxznXQa/VU1jLba39P+XwiRIA agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.3]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi wiktoriavh! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 1992, received 2648 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6543.8, received 8698.8
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you check your authorized keys _on GitHub_ (using the web interface)? Is your local SSH key there?

Comment: Yes it's there. It gets added during gh auth login, I manually checked as well.

Comment: What do you get for `ssh -Tv git@github.com`?

Comment: Still the same, permission denied.

Comment: What else did it say? That `-v` is there to provide verbose output.

Comment: As of two days ago I get authenticated, but still am unable to clone with git. I have appended the output of the command in the main post.

Comment: According to the `ssh` debug output, ssh offered C:\\Users\\Wiktoria\\.ssh\\id_ed25519 to the server (same as `gh`), and the server didn't accept it. ssh successfully authenticated with the "w.dev+github@mailbox.org" key that it got from the ssh agent. It seems that you should be using this "w.dev+github@mailbox.org" key here instead of id_ed25519.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I created another set of keys and named it "github", which uses the email you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never been able to use SSH on Windows... in a corporate environment (at work): egress SSH is generally blocked.

But if it is not the case for you, then check with `ssh-add -l` that your key is listed. If not, in a Powershell session:

```
Start-Service ssh-agent
ssh-add C:\Users\Wiktoria\.ssh\id_ed25519
```

And, for testing, set your configuration to directly point to `github.com` instead of using a custom hostname like `gh-cli`.

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile C:\Users\Wiktoria\.ssh\id_ed25519
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Then double-check again your SSH connection, using the verbose output as suggested:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

Comment: I have added the key using `ssh-add` already and I double checked with the flag as well. The config file I change the Host to `github.com`, and the output of the last command I appended to my main post. I get a uthenticated, like when doing `ssh git@github.com`, but still unable to git clone.

Comment: @Mähnenwolf What [`gh auth status`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_status) returns? Did you try to use a token instead (just to test an HTTPS clone, instead of an SSH one)?

Comment: HTTPS works. In my main post I am writing that I am using gh cli, but the issues exists with just git as well.

Comment: @Mähnenwolf Do you mean a `git clone git@github.com:wiktoriavh/myRepo` fails? Even though a `ssh -T git@github.com` gives you a "`Hi wiktoriavh! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Mähnenwolf What is the exact error message when you use git clone? "Permission denied (publickey)."? Can you try with an SSH key without passphrase, for testing?

Comment: It is a ssh key without passphrase. In the main post I have a screenshot of it. The screenshot uses gh repo clone, but using git clone results in the exact same error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255612/discussion-between-vonc-and-mahnenwolf).

Comment: @Mähnenwolf Don't forget to check the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255612/discussion-between-vonc-and-mahnenwolf